# How to reduce image width

Tags: html, image, media-queries, parallax, image-resizing

I would like to know how to resize image found in this section when screen width reduces. The image is part of parallax effect, but it is not the background, it is the thing that is scrolling (which I usually found as a text).

```
<div class="bgimg-1 w3-display-container" id="home">
  <div class="w3-display-middle" style="white-space:nowrap;">
    <img src="logo3.png" alt="Logo" style="width:1000px;height:750px;">
  </div>
</div>
```

I fixed the dimensions with *style*, but need to reduce it more when needed.
At the beginning of the entire code, before that section, the option I have available is

```
   @media only screen and (max-device-width: 1024px) {
.bgimg-1, .bgimg-2, .bgimg-3 {
    background-attachment: scroll;  
 }
}
```

which is only turning off parallax scrolling for smaller widths. The references to images found in this part are the background images, which I do not need to resize. 
What should I include in order to resize the image in the section mentioned earlier (not the backgrounds)?

Answer (score 0):

If you happen to be using Bootstrap, Materialize or any other responsive CSS template, just leave your image in its original resolution and place its tag inside a responsive container. With Bootstrap, where each view is split in 12 columns, it would look like:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-offset-3">
        <img src="logo3.png" alt="Logo" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Let me know if you want anything different from this.